# how to access a list item within a method from another method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please how do i access the items witnin random in Details:
My goal is to be able to show the individual details in my app as soon as i click the item but it is not coming from my database yet.
Thank you

```
public ActionResult Random()
{
    var movie = new Movies() { Name = "Shreck" };

    var customers = new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "Mark" },
        new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "Shantia" },
        new Customer {Id = 3, Name = "Bruth" },
        new Customer {Id = 5, Name = "Hamai" },
        new Customer {Id = 6, Name = "Saebi" }
    };

    var viewModel = new RandomViewModel {
        Movies = movie,
        Customers = customers
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}


public ActionResult Details(int id, String name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted for the tag spam. This has absolutely nothing to do with Java and PHP. Please do not add unrelated tags to your question as a means of drawing more attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Details` method you need to be able to query the Movie or Customer by the id, and return said Movie or Customer in the View() call as a view model parameter. Try this:

```
    private List<Movie> _movies;
    private List<Customer> _customers;

    public HomeController() // name of your controller
    {
        _movies = new List<Movie>() { new Movie { Name = "Shreck" } };

        _customers = new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "Mark" },
            new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "Shantia" },
            new Customer {Id = 3, Name = "Bruth" },
            new Customer {Id = 5, Name = "Hamai" },
            new Customer {Id = 6, Name = "Saebi" }
        };
    }

    public ActionResult Random()
    {
        var viewModel = new RandomViewModel
        {
            Movies = _movies,
            Customers = _customers
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }


    public ActionResult MovieDetails(string name)
    {
        Movie movie = _movies.Where(m => m.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(movie); // make sure you have a view called "MovieDetails" with "Movie" designated as the view model
    }

    public ActionResult CustomerDetails(int id)
    {
        Customer customer = _customers.Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(customer); // make sure you have a view called "CustomerDetails" with "Customer" designated as the view model
    }
```

Your model is also a bit unclear - if movies and customers are not separate entities, i.e. if each movie has multiple customers, then I would incorporate the Customer entity into the Movie entity & pass the Movie entity into RandomViewModel and return that & in Details page, query the selected movie by Id & return it as well as its related customers.

Comment: This won't work because the controller is created per-request, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Looks better :)